# Replace items like A2 as AA in the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of items, like "**A2**BCO6" and "AB**C2**O6". I want to replace them as **A2**BCO6--> **AA**BCO6   and AB**C2**O6 --> AB**CC**O6. The number of items are much more than presented here.

```
My dataframe is like:
    listAB:
       Finctional_Group
    0   Ba2NbFeO6
    1   Ba2ScIrO6
    3   MnPb2WO6
```

I create a duplicate array and tried to replace with following way:

```
B = ["Ba2", "Pb2"]
C = ["BaBa", "PbPb"]
for i,j in range(len(B)), range(len(C)):
   listAB["Finctional_Group"]= listAB["Finctional_Group"].str.strip().str.replace(B[i], C[j])
```

But it does not produce correct output. The output is like:

```
listAB:
   Finctional_Group
0   PbPbNbFeO6
1   PbPbScIrO6
3   MnPb2WO6
```

Please suggest the necessary correction in the code.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want the first occurance to be replaced only and not the other onces? It is not quite clear in this case. Or do you just want to omit `O6` ?

Comment: No, it is not as such. Where ever 2 is written that element is need to be repeated. For example A2B is like AAB and AB2 is like ABB. Also you can see there, the last item as "MnPb2WO6" that is to be written as "MnPbPbWO6"

Comment: with that logic, it should be `MnPbPbWOOOOOO` no?

Answer (score 0):

I used for simplicity purpose [chemparse](https://pypi.org/project/chemparse/) package that seems to suite your needs.

As always we import the required packages, in this case `chemparse` and `pandas`.

```
import chemparse 
import pandas as pd
```

then we create a `pandas.DataFrame` object like in your example with your example data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["Finctional_Group"], data=["Ba2NbFeO6", "Ba2ScIrO6", "MnPb2WO6"]
)
```

Our parser function will use `chemparse.parse_formula` which returns a dict of element and their frequency in a molecular formula.

```
def parse_molecule(molecule: str) -> dict:
    # initializing empty string
    molecule_in_string = ""
    # iterating over all key & values in dict
    for key, value in chemparse.parse_formula(molecule).items():
        # appending number of elements to string
        molecule_in_string += key * int(value)
    return molecule_in_string
```

`molecule_in_string` contains the molecule formula without numbers now. We just need to map this function to all elements in our dataframe column. For that we can do

```
df = df.applymap(parse_molecule)
print(df)
```

which returns:

```
0    BaBaNbFeOOOOOO
1    BaBaScIrOOOOOO
2     MnPbPbWOOOOOO
dtype: object
```

Source code for chemparse: https://gitlab.com/gmboyer/chemparse